# genesis header add class when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, genesis

With this code I want to add another css-class to the site-header.
 I'm not sure how to embed .js in php.

```
//Add shrink class to header on scroll.
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_site-header', 'my_custom_genesis_header_class' );
function my_custom_genesis_header_class( $attributes ) {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.site-header').outerHeight()) {
            $(".site-header").addClass("shrink");
        } else {
            $(".site-header").removeClass("shrink");
        }

    $attributes['class'] .= ' shrink';
    return $attributes;
}
```

I would like to include this code in the functions.php of my child-theme. But i dont know why it's not working...

Comment: Please explain what exactly does not work?

Comment: with this code i want to add another css-class to the site-header, but this code doesnot work... i dont know exacktly how to embed .js in php. that's my problem